# Boss asked me to create a spinnable image in a website, but . .

Tags: user-interface

. . . I'm not a programmer, although I do have a basic knowledge of programming and have passed one college course in it.

Here is what I am being asked to do.  I created this 3d model for my job in Sketchup, then screencasted rotating it through different angles so that various of our design team could get a good visual of an underground communication wire system that they have to be aware of.  My boss asked me kind of off-the-cuff "hey could you put this in a webpage we could visit and manually rotate in all spherical directions?" That was three months ago and that particular project is complete but I never did the webpage my boss was inquiring into. But now he wants me to look into it again.

In this particular post I am not really asking "how" but rather would like to be pointed in the best direction for creating a user/visitor rotatable object in a website.  I am willing and intending to learn a good dose of programming if required.

Here is the youtube video of the MP4 that I will be using.

[MP4 of me rotating object inside the 3d modeling software Sketchup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1cZksoK2FUc&t=5s)

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found a native Sketchup solution.  Just upload the sketchup model file to 3d Warehouse and go from there.  Here is my actual model, globally rotatable.  Click on eye button to interact with it.  Click on hard-to-see full-screen icon at bottom right of model window to expand to full screen.
[3d globally rotatable model](https://3dwarehouse.sketchup.com/model/6d98dd18-9e6e-4e16-b712-66177729752a/PipeGrateTilt)